# DOM manipulation with PhantomJS

Tags: dom, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to create screenshots from arbitrary URLs. Before the screenshot is taken, I want to manipulate the page DOM to remove all drop-down menus, as PhantomJS renders them incorrectly in the top left-hand corner of the page (a known Phantom [issue](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=601).)

I have a simple DOM script to do this with:

```
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

    for (var i=0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('select')[i].style.visibility="hidden";
    }
```

This has been tested and works fine as stand-alone Javascript. It doesn't however work inside the PhantomJS code I am using to collect the screenshots (last part shown):

```
  page.open(address, function (status) {

    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {

            var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

            for (var i=0; i < selects.length; i++) {
                document.getElementsByTagName('select')[i].style.visibility="hidden";
            }

            page.render(output);

            phantom.exit();

        }, 200);
    }
});
```

Some pages are still rendering with a select box in the wrong place. I'd appreciate help either solving the original PhantomJS rendering bug or hiding the drop-down menus in the DOM. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run it in the right context, i.e. inside the page with `page.evaluate`. There are many [examples included with PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/tree/master/examples) which demonstrate this, e.g. [useragent.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/useragent.js).

Comment: @ariyahidayat Hi, my friend! please help me with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906200/real-time-web-page-screenshot-using-phantomjs)

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't work? 
I used your cached selects variable in the for loop instead of re-selecting the elements from the DOM to improve performance.

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select'); 
for (var i=0; i < selects.length; i++) { 
   selects[i].style.visibility="hidden"; 
}
```