# Real time web page screenshot using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, php, screenshot

I wanted to use html2canvas to let users take screenshots from anything things they did in a website, but in my recent project I'm using mask-image CSS property which is pretty new and unfortunately, html2canvas doesn't support that at all!

The first question is that how can I make html2canvas support that property? is it possible and how?

Then I wanted to use another library to take screenshots, which the most famous one is [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html)

Luckily [this package](https://github.com/microweber/screen) which is using phantomjs works cool with mask-image but I don't know how to use it in a realtime mode I mean when the user did something in a page take a screenshot that edited page without loading that. Because phantomjs loads the URL(changes will be disappeared) and then take the picture of that.

I'm ok with other sources too (just in a case that it supports the mask-image CSS property)